# How do I implement the basic authentication in Spring Cloud API Gateway?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth, basic-authentication, bearer-token

I have 2 secured resource microservices and 1 authentication service and another API Gateway.

Authentication service can generate JWT Token given username and password. It also can validate a JWT token.

So, I want to implement security at the API Gateway only such that on receiving a request, it will first fetch a bearer token from the authentication service and forward the request to the secured resource service. I would like to get some idea how to implement that in API Gateway. Should I make it just in an aggregate fashion, like it would be a sync call which will first make a request to auth service and next forward the request to resource service?

Now, if I want to add the support of OAuth as well, which I know the spring cloud API Gateway already has the support for this via global filters.

But, I am wondering about the legacy bearer token which is generated by the custom authentication service.. How do I ensure this?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!